FastAPI dependency refactor
I'm refactoring an endpoint (path operator function) in FastAPI that has two problems: 1. It is performing too much business logic.  2. It takes in a LOT of dependencies in order to perform this logic.
I've moved the business logic into an order service so the complexity now no longer resides in my path operator function.  So it now looks like this:
@router.get("/{order_id}", tags=["orders"], response_model=OrderOutput)
async def get_order_by_id(
    order_id: int,
    session: Session = Depends(get_db),
    wm_db: Session = Depends(get_wm_db),
    sm_session: Session = Depends(get_sm_db),
    actor_service: ActorService = Depends(get_actor_service),
    event_service: EventService = Depends(get_event_service),
    order_service: OrderService = Depends(get_order_service),
    item_service: ItemService = Depends(get_item_service),
    sm_service: StandardMaterialService = Depends(get_standard_material_service),
    comment_service: CommentService = Depends(get_comment_service),
    wm_service: WorkManagerService = Depends(get_wm_service),
    warehouse_service: WarehouseInventoryService = Depends(get_warehouse_inventory_service),
) -> OrderOutput:

    return order_service.get_order_by_id(order_id, all the dependencies...)

Here are my questions:
Is there a cleaner way to get all these dependencies into my path operator?
Due to the refactor, the order service is now the class that depends on these things. Is there a cleaner way to get them into my order service so that they don't have to all pass through the path operator function?

Why doesn't your get_order_service function depend on the parameters it need to create the service instead of taking them as arguments? That way you'd only have a dependency on getting the order service in your controller, while everything else would be the responsibility of the order service constructor function

That was the change that cleaned it up and got the dependencies down to the level of the order service where they belong.  Thanks!

Here's the refactor:
from OrderService import get_order_service

@router.get("/{order_id}", tags=["orders"], response_model=OrderOutput)
async def get_order_by_id(
    order_id: int,   
    order_service: OrderService = Depends(get_order_service),   
) -> OrderOutput:

    return order_service.get_order_by_id(order_id)

# OrderService.py
def get_order_service (
       session: Session = Depends(get_db),
       wm_db: Session = Depends(get_wm_db),
       sm_session: Session = Depends(get_sm_db),
       actor_service: ActorService = Depends(get_actor_service),
       event_service: EventService = Depends(get_event_service),
       item_service: ItemService = Depends(get_item_service),
       sm_service: StandardMaterialService = 
           Depends(get_standard_material_service),
       comment_service: CommentService = Depends(get_comment_service),
       wm_service: WorkManagerService = Depends(get_wm_service),
       warehouse_service: WarehouseInventoryService = 
           Depends(get_warehouse_inventory_service)):

    return OrderService(session,wm_db,sm_session,actor_service,...)

class OrderService:

    def __init__ (self,
       session: Session,
       wm_db: Session,
       sm_session: Session,
       actor_service: ActorService,
       event_service: EventService,
       item_service: ItemService,
       sm_service: StandardMaterialService ,
       comment_service: CommentService ,
       wm_service: WorkManagerService ,
       warehouse_service: WarehouseInventoryService 
    ):
    self.session = session
    self.wm_db = wm_db
    ...

    def get_order_by_id(self, order_id):
       # biz logic that uses all the dependencies that are instance variables of this class

